# Sparrow.Chart.WinRT.45 Payload file 'C:\...\' does not exist errors

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

When I add Sparrow.Chart.WinRT.45 through NuGet package manager, upon attempting to compile, I am faced with

Error   7   Payload file 'C:\Repository\Application\packages\Sparrow.Chart.WinRT.13.1.0.114\lib\netcore45\Sparrow.Chart.WinRT.45\Sparrow.Chart.WinRT.45\Legend\Legend.xaml' does not exist. Electroencephalograph
Error   8   Payload file 'C:\Repository\Application\packages\Sparrow.Chart.WinRT.13.1.0.114\lib\netcore45\Sparrow.Chart.WinRT.45\Sparrow.Chart.WinRT.45\Themes\generic.xaml' does not exist.    Electroencephalograph
Error   9   Payload file 'C:\Repository\Application\packages\Sparrow.Chart.WinRT.13.1.0.114\lib\netcore45\Sparrow.Chart.WinRT.45\Sparrow.Chart.WinRT.45\Themes\Styles.xaml' does not exist. Electroencephalograph

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In case if you couldn't figured out still, the path to the .xaml files are wrong. If you check the packages you will see that it has one `Sparrow.Chart.WinRT.45\` folder, but the VS search them in `Sparrow.Chart.WinRT.45\Sparrow.Chart.WinRT.45`. So you should create a folder in the packages folder and copy those files to there.